# Google Deployment Manager: Whats the equivalent of Allow HTTP traffic when creating a compute engine instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, firewall, google-deployment-manager

I have tried creating a firewall rule with sourceTags and have my VM tagged with http. But it still does not allow HTTP traffic. Why is that?

```
resources:
- type: compute.v1.instance
  name: vm-test
  properties:
    zone: {{ properties["zone"] }}
    machineType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/zones/{{ properties["zone"] }}/machineTypes/f1-micro
    # For examples on how to use startup scripts on an instance, see:
    #   https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        diskName: disk-{{ env["deployment"] }}
        sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-9
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/global/networks/default
      # Access Config required to give the instance a public IP address
      accessConfigs:
      - name: External NAT
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
    metadata:
      items:
        - key: startup-script
          value: |
             #!/bin/bash
             apt-get update
             apt-get install -y apache2
    tags:
      items:
        - http
```

Answer (score 0):

Tag has to be the same as the network tag attached. The default ones are "http-server" or "https-server", so the script should have that present like this:

```
tags    
  items
    - http-server
    - https-server
```

Bear in mind also to properly configure firewall rule and check that http server is running and listening on that port.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the firewall section there as well. Here is the one which is working for me:

```
resources:
- type: compute.v1.firewall
  name: tcp-firewall-rule
  properties:
    network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/global/networks/default
    sourceRanges: ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    targetTags: ["http","http-server"]
    allowed:
     - IPProtocol: TCP
       ports: ["80"]
- type: compute.v1.instance
  name: vm-test
  properties:
    zone: {{ properties['zone'] }}
    machineType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env['project'] }}/zones/{{ properties['zone'] }}/machineTypes/f1-micro
    tags:
     items: ["http","http-server"]
    metadata:
      items:
      # For more ways to use startup scripts on an instance, see:
      #   https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript
      - key: startup-script
        value: |
          #!/bin/bash
          apt-get update
          apt-get install -y apache2
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        diskName: disk-{{ env["deployment"] }}
        sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-9
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/global/networks/default
      # Access Config required to give the instance a public IP address
      accessConfigs:
      - name: External NAT
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
```